# What to change fragments according to time of the day

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a scenario where I have a `ViewPager` with 6 `Fragments` .

I want to show first 3 `Fragments` at morning time i.e from 0:00AM till 11:59AM in the `ViewPager` .

I want to show then next 3 `Fragments` at afternoon time i.e from 12:00PM till 23:59PM

Currently I am checking the time in the `onResume()` of the `Activity` and updating the `ViewPager's Adapter` .

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        globalCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        timeOfDay = globalCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        if (timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12) {
            layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_morning_background));
            mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mViewPager.destroyDrawingCache();
        } else {
            layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_background));
            mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mViewPager.destroyDrawingCache();
        }
    }
```

**2 problems with my implementation**:

1. If the application is open at 11:59AM and is in the foreground till
   12:00PM the `ViewPager` wont get updated.
2. If I take the application
       to background the `ViewPager's Adapter` is getting refresh
       everytime.

How can I update the `ViewPager` once and load the related `Fragments` whenever the user open the application ?

Comment: Check the `AlarmManager`

Comment: You can register a broadcast with alarm manager on specific time which will fire that broadcast accordingly then use that broadcast logic to resolve your problem.

Comment: I am looking code implementation. I tried working with AlarmManager. But unable to figure out the logical implementation.

Comment: A little code implementation will be of great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirement, your app works perfectly when you go to background and coming to forground.

So the problem is foreground senario, So we can use Handler for that.

I am just giving hint here, If you do this it will work fine.

```
private int mSession = -1;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    update();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int min = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    if (((hours == 11) || (hours == 23)) && min > 45) {
        // this is just we are starting if the current time is 11: 45 or 23:45 or more
        // We ar beliving that user may be in this screen max 15 mins
        int currentSecond = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, (60 - currentSecond) * 1000);
    }
}

private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        update();

        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 60 * 1000);
    }
};

private void update() {
    globalCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeOfDay = globalCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    if (timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12) {

        if (mSession != 1) {
            updateFirstHalf();
        }
        mSession = 1;
    } else {

        if (mSession != 2) {
            updateSecondHalf();
        }
        mSession = 2;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
}

private void updateFirstHalf() {
    layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_morning_background));
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mViewPager.destroyDrawingCache();
}

private void updateSecondHalf() {
    layout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gradient_background));
    mSectionsPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mViewPager.destroyDrawingCache();
}
```

Comment: `updateSecondHalf()` is getting called everytime when I come frome background to forground. Its refreshing all the `Fragments` again

Comment: Yes may be you time in afternoon so when you come to this screen it will call and it should call then only you can render your background.

Comment: It's refreshing all the Fragments again - then you should write this logic in Activity and in your fragment you should not give any bg, it should be transparent.

Comment: This logic is in the activity only. and Fragment is transparent only. no background

Comment: why are you declaring `mSession = -1` inside `onResume()` ?
Removing that line fixed my problem.

Comment: I think you should use `Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY`. Because it will return time in 24 hour format

Answer (score 0):

Use `FirebaseJobDispatcher` or `BroadcastReceiver` and in register events for the time when your UI should update.

in your activity or fragment register broadcast receiver and update your UI accordingly.

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,12);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
Intent _myIntent = new Intent(context, Notify.class);
PendingIntent _myPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123, _myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|  Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), _myPendingIntent);
```

in Your Activity

```
class MyActivity extends Activity{
  //Register and unregister your receiver in onResume and onPause
  class Notify extends BroadcastReceiver{
    //Implement OnReceive
  }
}
```

Comment: A little code implementation of the broadcast recevier will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

This is way to register your broadcast with alarm manager ....and do the rest of logic from your broadcast

```
public void registerBroadcastWithAM() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourBroadcastReceiver.class);


       AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar firstTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar secondTurn = Calendar.getInstance();

        // set times
        firstTime .set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
        firstTime .set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);

        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        secondTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        secondTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


        alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
        alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, secondTime.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent2);

    }
```

Comment: As I am opening the application now with your implementation. The fragments are not changing. I guess you are only looking for specific time. What can be the possible solution. If the user opens the app at any time, the related fragments should pop up.